# Sonarqube difference between sonar way profile and sonarqube java rules repository

Tags: java, sonarqube, rules

What is the difference between the Sonarqube java plugin repository under rules>repository> Sonarqube Java rules and the default profile Sonar way under quality profiles. The first one has 322 rules, while the second one has 229. What is missing from the Sonar way profile? I am using Sonarqube 5.2 server.

Answer (score 3):

First, the version of your Java Plugin is more relevant than the version of your SonarQube server. The server ships with a copy of the Java plugin, but the two are versioned independently, and it can never be assumed that you're running the version of the plugin that ships with the server.

To answer your question, the Sonar Way profiles are designed to be absolutely non-controversial out of the box. So rules about what line '{' should be on, for instance, aren't included. There are also rules that are desirable only in certain coding situations. For instance, not everyone is going to be interested in the proper use of Struts, so those get left off too.

Comment: Thanks. Java plugin version is 3.6 . So java plugin is also more frequently updated.

Comment: Yes, we try to release often to continuously provide improvements of the plugin (new rules, better accuracy, bug fixes, etc...). Note that version 3.11 should be released pretty soon! Don't hesitate to upgrade!